# Including views using merge tag and ViewStub

Tags: android

I wanted to extend my `TableLayout` with some additional rows through `ViewStab` element. This is my `Activity`'s layout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root_table_layout">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Row 1"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Row 2"/>
    </TableRow>

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/view_stub_1"
        android:layout="@layout/merge_table_1"/>

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/view_stub_2"
        android:layout="@layout/merge_table_2"/>

</TableLayout>
```

Either `view_stub_1` or `view_stub_2` is inflated on `Activity` `onCreate` (it depends on app's condition).

`ViewStub` was supposed to inflate a layout defined with `<merge>` tag as the root element. Like this:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Row 5"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Row 6"/>
    </TableRow>

</merge>
```

But when the `Activity` was about to start, I got this exception:

> merge can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and
>   attachToRoot=true
>   - worked with getLayoutInflater

Answer (score 9):

It seems like `<merge>` tag is not supported by `ViewStub` element right now:

> The only drawback of ViewStub is that it currently does not support
>   the  tag.

[Romain Guy's post on layout tricks](http://www.curious-creature.com/2009/03/16/android-layout-tricks-4-optimize-part-2/)

In the end I used `Activity`'s `LayoutInflater` to include additional rows into the `TableLayout`:

```
ViewGroup rootTableLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root_table_layout);
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.merge_table_1, rootTableLayout, true);
```

Since I only wanted to attach a few `TableRows` at the and of the `ViewGroup`, this solution works. For more complicated scenario (dynamically include `TableRows` in the middle of a `TableLayout`), I still don't know what would be a proper way to do it.

Comment: seems to still be a problem a few years later